# Cannot resolve symbol "AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER" In FirebaseUI

Tags: android

I am using `FirebaseUI` with Google and Email provider in an application and it is working fine. now i am adding Phone varification to this but when adding `AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER` in code the editor showing `cannot resolve symbol PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER`. I am following [FirebaseUI-auth readme](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).

Here is my code:

```
private void showLoginPage(){
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
       .createSignInIntentBuilder()
       .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
       .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()))
       .build(), LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency and sync your project:

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

For new version is available, just add this dependency and sync your project:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'
```

Then press ALt + Enter for import:

```
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
```